# Xcode Interface Builder - Rulers/object guides

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, rulers

In Xcode, does the interface builder have some sort of customisable rulers like in Photoshop to help me position elements correctly?

I know it does those red lines which appear, but I mean lines that you can position yourself.

Thanks, Dan.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question.

Basically click "Editor" on the menu bar. Then click "Add Horizontal Guide" or click "Add Vertical Guide".

Thats it, they are very good and they also show their position information. Very helpful :)

Comment: In xcode 6.4, I can't see " Add Horizontal Guide" or  "Add Vertical Guide".

Answer (score 4):

For xcode 6 it is Editor>Canvas>Add Horizontal Guide

Comment: Strangely these options are greyed out for me, but using the keyboard shortcut works. Afterwards these commands are no longer greyed out.

Answer (score 4):

After **xcode Version 6.4** you can find this option here.

[image]

Or you can also use **shortcut** as shown in image.

Comment: It's available in 9.2 i have checked it. Please verify once again from your side.

Comment: Okay, you're correct, sorry for the false information. I was actually looking for vertical guides in the *code* view, not GUI designer.

Comment: I don't see this in 14.3.1

Comment: It is still there. please go to your storyboard. select particular view and then click on EDITOR -> GUIDES.

Answer (score 1):

these are the keyboard shortcuts

```
⌘ _ : add Horizontal guide line
⌘ | : add Vertical guide line
```

to remove a vertical guide, drag it out of the view.. vertically

to remove a horizontal guide, drag it out of the view.. horizontally

[image: remove Xcode guide]